# What's the standard way to give a set of different clickable options all submitting the same form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a PHP-generated page which is displaying some data about a set of films. The page is updated using POST. The form only shows films starting with a particular letter. I want to present a set of clickable options at the top of the screen, each of which is a letter. So if you click on "B" it submits the form and re-draws the page showing only films that start with B. (I know, Ajax would be a better way to do this, but I'm trying to get something done quickly).

Anyway, I know I can do this by having each link be a Javascript call which sets the value of a hidden field and then submits the form, or I could do it by having each letter be a button which has a particular value and submits the form directly, but neither of those strikes me as particularly elegant. Is there a standard way to do this? Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a number of submit buttons and give each a different name. Then you test to see which submit was pressed based on what is included in the POST array.

Please note that you can use the [image input type](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_type.asp) in place of the submit input type so that you can substitute your own image, etc for your button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you pretty much cover the options you have. I generally see it done with javascript and hrefs because people don't like to style real buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Internet Explorer (6/7?) doesn't POST a variable with the **name** of the button on an <input type="image"> - it only posts variables with **name_x** and **name_y** with the coordinates of where on the button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to submit the form as you are not really using it.

Why not just a set of hyperlinks B

Comment: but then how would I set variables that I needed to pass in to the PHP script? I could do this by adding them on to the URL of each link, but then my script would need to check $_GET as well as $_POST, which feels wrong, somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Use several different submit buttons, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="letter" value="A" />
<input type="submit" name="letter" value="B" />
<input type="submit" name="letter" value="C" />
...
```